# How to specify static python for boost.python?

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python, linkage

I want to link python to boost statically to use python and boost.python for each DLL-library inside one process independently from other DLL-libraries.
Standard configure API doesn't have any options to do such things.

Is there isset way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This possibility exists on unix if we use

```
./configure --disable-shared
```

for python building. As result python is built as static library and boost python links this static library.
On Windows system it is needed to download python sources and to change project to static library build manually. And after that to specify library path to this static library for boost sources.